# How to declare variable with result of query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I created function and want to assign variable result of query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetData
(
    OUT outValue integer
)
AS $$
DECLARE
  records "Records";
BEGIN  
  records := (SELECT "Value1" FROM "Records");
  outValue := (SELECT sum("Value1") FROM records)
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But, postgresql say's:

```
"ERROR: subquery in an expression returned more than one row."
```

If declare a variable of type `<"Records"%ROWTYPE>`, we have same result error.

How to declare variable with result of query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create temporary table inside your function and use it for queries after populating:

```
create or replace function GetData()
returns integer
as $$
declare
    outValue int;
begin
    create temporary table records(Value1 int);

    insert into records
    select Value1 from Table1;

    outValue := (select sum(Value1) from records);

    return outValue;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/8acf3/1)</kbd>**

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to return a single value why not declare the function as `returns integer` and use something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetData()
  returns integer
AS $$
  SELECT sum("Value1")::integer FROM "Records";
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Btw: I would highly recommend to stop using quoted identifiers and get rid of the double quotes. That will save you a lot of trouble in the long run.

Comment: Thank you for advice, but i want to make one query and then results of query to make another queries.

Answer (score 1):

Why not combine the queries?

```
...
BEGIN
  SELECT sum("Value1") INTO outValue FROM "Records";
END;
...
```